# Can't get Android SDK or Eclipse ADT to work

Tags: android

I'm having major issues getting the sdk to work with eclipse. I installed everything, and then tried to run a project on the SDK emulator and got these errors:

```
[2012-02-02 19:59:45 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/swipe/DrawView;
[2012-02-02 19:59:45 - SwipeActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/swipe/DrawView;
```

I then restarted Eclipse, and cleaned the project and rebuilt it. Neither helped, so I uninstalled the SDK, ADT, and Eclipse. I then reinstalled all of them, except ADT. I get this error when installing it in Eclipse:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

It seems I have regressed. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried to do this on both my Mac laptop and Windows desktop. The described problem above was done on my windows. On my Mac, I am still at the first problem (ADT is installed and everything). This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: You should consider reinstalling (or even updating) your eclipse distribution. Are you using eclipse for other projects? If so, does it work with them?

Comment: I reinstalled it a few times, and tried updating.